# Why is Contact Form email sending "Value" instead of "Name" for certain fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using premade code for a Contact Form that utilizes Google Scripts. It successfully sends the email and formats it decently to my inbox, but still there are problems. I have a list of questions about it at the end.

Here is the code:

Form Handler Javascript:

```
(function() {
  function validEmail(email) { // see:
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return re.test(email);
  }

  function validateHuman(honeypot) {
    if (honeypot) {  //if hidden form filled up
      console.log("Robot Detected!");
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("Welcome Human!");
    }
  }

  // get all data in form and return object
  function getFormData() {
    var form = document.getElementById("gform");
    var elements = form.elements;

    var fields = Object.keys(elements).filter(function(k) {
          return (elements[k].name !== "honeypot");
    }).map(function(k) {

      if(elements[k].name !== undefined) {
        return elements[k].name;
      // special case for Edge's html collection
      }else if(elements[k].length > 0){
        return elements[k].item(0).name;
      }

    }).filter(function(item, pos, self) {
      return self.indexOf(item) == pos && item;
    });

    var formData = {};
    fields.forEach(function(name){
      var element = elements[name];

      // singular form elements just have one value

      formData[name] = element.value;                     

      // when our element has multiple items, get their values         


      if (element.length) {
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
          var item = element.item(i);
          if (item.checked || item.selected) {
            data.push(item.value);
          }
        }
        formData[name] = data.join(', ');
      } 


    });

    // add form-specific values into the data
    formData.formDataNameOrder = JSON.stringify(fields);
    formData.formGoogleSheetName = form.dataset.sheet || "responses"; // default sheet name
    formData.formGoogleSendEmail = form.dataset.email || ""; // no email by default

    console.log(formData);
    return formData;
  }

  function handleFormSubmit(event) {  // handles form submit without any jquery
    event.preventDefault();           // we are submitting via xhr below
    var data = getFormData();         // get the values submitted in the form

    /* OPTION: Remove this comment to enable SPAM prevention, see README.md
    if (validateHuman(data.honeypot)) {  //if form is filled, form will not be submitted
      return false;
    }
    */

    if( data.email && !validEmail(data.email) ) {   // if email is not valid show error
      var invalidEmail = document.getElementById("email-invalid");
      if (invalidEmail) {
        invalidEmail.style.display = "block";
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      disableAllButtons(event.target);
      var url = event.target.action;  //
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', url);
      // xhr.withCredentials = true;
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          console.log( xhr.status, xhr.statusText )
          console.log(xhr.responseText);


          //document.getElementById("gform").style.display = "none"; // hide form

          /*
          var thankYouMessage = document.getElementById("thankyou_message");
          if (thankYouMessage) {
            thankYouMessage.style.display = "block";
          }
          */



          return;
      };
      // url encode form data for sending as post data
      var encoded = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) {
          return encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[k])
      }).join('&')
      xhr.send(encoded);
    }
  }
  function loaded() {
    console.log("Contact form submission handler loaded successfully.");
    // bind to the submit event of our form
    var form = document.getElementById("gform");
    form.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmit, false);
  };
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loaded, false);

  function disableAllButtons(form) {
    var buttons = form.querySelectorAll("button");
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].disabled = true;
    }
  }
})();
```

Contact Form HTML:

```
<section id="contact-form">

            <div class="content-wrap">
                <h4 class="form-heading">To send your general questions or comments, please use the contact form below.</h4>
            </div>


            <form id="gform"
                  class="contact-form" method="post" 
                  action="(Google Scripts URL)"
                  enctype="text/plain">

                <p>
                    <label for="name">Your Name <font face="Arial" color="red">*</font></label>
                    <input type="text" style="height:35px;" class="heighttext required" name="name" id="name" class="required" title="* Please provide your name">
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="email">Your Email <font face="Arial" color="red">*</font></label>
                    <input type="text" style="height:35px;" class="heighttext required" name="email" id="email" class="email required" title="* Please provide an email address">
                </p>

                <p>

<label>Your Location <font face="Arial" color="red">*</font></label>


<select name="Location" id="column_select" style="height:35px;" class="required" title=" * Please provide your location">
    <option selected value="col00">-- State --</option>       
    <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
    <option value="California">California</option>
    <option value="Florida">Florida</option>  
</select>

<select name="City" id="layout_select" style="height:35px;">     
    <option disabled selected value="Florida">-- City --</option> 
    <option name="Alachua" value="Florida_Alachua">Alachua</option>   
    <option name="Alford" value="Florida_Alford">Alford</option>     
</select>

     </p>           


                <p>
                    <label for="subject">I am interested in the following... <font face="Arial" color="red">*</font> </label>

                    <select style="height:35px;" class="required" title=" * Please provide a subject">
                        <option disabled selected value>-- select an option --</option>
                        <option value="volvo">Your position on...</option>
                        <option name="How to Donate" value="saab">How to donate</option>
                        <option name="How can I join your team or help?" value="mercedes">How can I join your team or help?</option>
                        <option name="Other" value="audi">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </p>



                <p>
                    <label for="comment">Your Message <font face="Arial" color="red">*</font></label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="comment" class="required" title="* Please provide your message"></textarea>
                </p>


                <p>
                    <div class="responsereqdiv">
                        <label for="comment">Response Requested? <font face="Arial" color="red" class="required" title="Please indicate whether you wish to be contacted.">*</font></label>

                        <label class="responsereqdiv1" for="YesResponse"> <input  type="radio" id="YesResponse" name="drone" />   Yes</label>

                        <label class="responsereqdiv2"  for="NoResponse"> <input type="radio" id="NoResponse" name="drone" /> No </label>

                    </div>    
                </p>



                <p>

                    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" id="submit" class="pp-btn special">
                    <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" id="contact-loader" alt="Loading...">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_message">
                    <!--<input type="hidden" name="target" value="">-->

                </p>




            </form>

            <div class="error-container"></div>
            <div id="message-sent2">Thank you! Your message has been sent.</div>

        </section><!-- #contact-form -->
```

Google Scripts code:

```
/******************************************************************************
 * This tutorial is based on the work of Martin Hawksey twitter.com/mhawksey  *
 * But has been simplified and cleaned up to make it more beginner friendly   *
 * All credit still goes to Martin and any issues/complaints/questions to me. *
 ******************************************************************************/

// if you want to store your email server-side (hidden), uncomment the next line
var TO_ADDRESS = "myemail@email.com";

// spit out all the keys/values from the form in HTML for email
// uses an array of keys if provided or the object to determine field order
function formatMailBody(obj, order) {
  var result = "";
  if (!order) {
    order = Object.keys(obj);
  }

  // loop over all keys in the ordered form data
  for (var idx in order) {
    var key = order[idx];
    result += "<h4 style='text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 0'>" + key + "</h4><div>" + sanitizeInput(obj[key]) + "</div>";
    // for every key, concatenate an `<h4 />`/`<div />` pairing of the key name and its value, 
    // and append it to the `result` string created at the start.
  }
  return result; // once the looping is done, `result` will be one long string to put in the email body
}

// sanitize content from the user - trust no one 
// ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#appendUntrusted(String)
function sanitizeInput(rawInput) {
   var placeholder = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(" ");
   placeholder.appendUntrusted(rawInput);

   return placeholder.getContent();
 }

function doPost(e) {

  try {
    Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger
    record_data(e);

    // shorter name for form data
    var mailData = e.parameters;

    // names and order of form elements (if set)
    var orderParameter = e.parameters.formDataNameOrder;
    var dataOrder;
    if (orderParameter) {
      dataOrder = JSON.parse(orderParameter);
    }

    // determine recepient of the email
    // if you have your email uncommented above, it uses that `TO_ADDRESS`
    // otherwise, it defaults to the email provided by the form's data attribute
    var sendEmailTo = (typeof TO_ADDRESS !== "undefined") ? TO_ADDRESS : mailData.formGoogleSendEmail;

    // send email if to address is set
    if (sendEmailTo) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: String(sendEmailTo),
        subject: "Contact form submitted",
        // replyTo: String(mailData.email), // This is optional and reliant on your form actually collecting a field named `email`
        htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData, dataOrder)
      });
    }

    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}


/**
 * record_data inserts the data received from the html form submission
 * e is the data received from the POST
 */
function record_data(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000); // hold off up to 30 sec to avoid concurrent writing

  try {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // log the POST data in case we need to debug it

    // select the 'responses' sheet by default
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetName = e.parameters.formGoogleSheetName || "responses";
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    var oldHeader = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var newHeader = oldHeader.slice();
    var fieldsFromForm = getDataColumns(e.parameters);
    var row = [new Date()]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp

    // loop through the header columns
    for (var i = 1; i < oldHeader.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column
      var field = oldHeader[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);

      // mark as stored by removing from form fields
      var formIndex = fieldsFromForm.indexOf(field);
      if (formIndex > -1) {
        fieldsFromForm.splice(formIndex, 1);
      }
    }

    // set any new fields in our form
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldsFromForm.length; i++) {
      var field = fieldsFromForm[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);
      newHeader.push(field);
    }

    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; // get next row
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

    // update header row with any new data
    if (newHeader.length > oldHeader.length) {
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, newHeader.length).setValues([newHeader]);
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(error);
  }
  finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
    return;
  }

}

function getDataColumns(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).filter(function(column) {
    return !(column === 'formDataNameOrder' || column === 'formGoogleSheetName' || column === 'formGoogleSendEmail' || column === 'honeypot');
  });
}

function getFieldFromData(field, data) {
  var values = data[field] || '';
  var output = values.join ? values.join(', ') : values;
  return output;
}
```

This is currently how the resulting email appears if, for instance, you choose Alachua, Florida as your location:

```
Name
TestName

Action
send_message

City
Florida_Alachua

Message
TestMessage

Email
test@test.com

Drone
on

Location
Florida
```

Questions:

-How can I make it say "Alachua" under City (instead of Florida_Alachua)?

-Why doesn't the selected "I'm interested in..." option appear in the email?

-How do I make the "Action send_message" part NOT appear in the email?

-How do I change "Drone: on" to instead read "Response Requested?" and then "Yes" or "No" depending on what the user selected?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You tagged PHP in your question. Where is the PHP part of your code?

Comment: Thank you. Removed PHP tag now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get just Alachu you need to set the value in the HTML to what you want it to send, options don't have a name attribute.
2. Your "I'm interested in" select has no name attribute, therefore the script is ignoring it.
3. To get rid of the action in the email make the following change:

```js
      for (var idx in order) {
        var key = order[idx];
        //Skip this entry into the email output if it is the Action
        if( key === 'Action') {continue}
        result += "<h4 style='text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 0'>" + key + "</h4><div>" + sanitizeInput(obj[key]) + "</div>";
        // for every key, concatenate an `<h4 />`/`<div />` pairing of the key name and its value, 
        // and append it to the `result` string created at the start.
      }
```

4. You need to add values to the radio buttons, and again just like 3 it is using the name of the radio button for the label. To fix what the email uses for the response do the following:

```html
    <label class="responsereqdiv1" for="YesResponse">
      <input  type="radio" id="YesResponse" name="drone" value="yes" />   Yes</label>
    
    <label class="responsereqdiv2"  for="NoResponse">
      <input type="radio" id="NoResponse" name="drone" value="no" /> No </label>
```

Fixing the naming is tougher because of how they did the loop to generate the HTML. Personally I would just change the name of the radio buttons to 'Response_Requested' and live with the underscore in the email.

Comment: Thank you!! Since name doesn't work for options, do you have advice on how to put the Text of the selection option instead? I am just looking for a way to return 'Alachua' without changing the value, because changing the value would break other code unfortunately. (specifically, it breaks this code: http://jsfiddle.net/a70zjg9p/10/ )

Comment: sry, this is the correct jsfiddle of the code that it would break, in case you wanted to take a look. https://jsfiddle.net/hmatt843/504dgmqy/19/